# how to convert decimal to binary by using repeated division in python

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

how to convert decimal to binary by using repeated division in python?

i know i have to use a while loop, and use modulus sign  and others {%} and {//} to do this...but i need some kind of example for me to understand  how its done so i can understand completely. 
CORRECT ME, if I'm wrong:

```
number = int(input("Enter a numberto convert into binary: "))

result = "" 
while number != 0:
    remainder = number % 2 # gives the exact remainder
    times = number // 2
    result = str(remainder) + result
    print("The binary representation is", result)
    break
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a "break" without any condition, makes the loop useless, so the code only executes once no matter what.

-

If you don't need to keep the original number, you can change "number" as you go.

If you do need to keep the original number, you can make a different variable like "times".

You seem to have mixed these two scenarios together.

-

If you want to print all the steps, the print will be inside the loop so it prints multiple times.

If you only want to print the final result, then the print goes outside the loop.

```
while number != 0:
    remainder = number % 2  # gives the exact remainder
    number = number // 2
    result = str(remainder) + result
print("The binary representation is", result)
```

-

The concatenation line:

Putting the print inside the loop might help you see how it works.

we can make an example:

the value in result might be "11010" (a string, with quotes)

the value in remainder might be 0 (an integer, no quotes)

str(remainder) turns the remainder into a string = "0" instead of 0

So when we look at the assignment statement:

```
result = str(remainder) + result
```

The right side of the assignment operator = is evaulated first.

The right side of the = is

```
str(remainder) + result
```

which, as we went over above has the values:

```
"0" + "11010"
```

This is string concatenation. It just puts one string on the end of the other one. The result is:

```
"0     11010"

"011010"
```

That is the value evaluated on the right side of the assignment statement.

```
result = "011010"
```

Now that is the value of result.

Answer (score 0):

```
B_Number = 0
cnt = 0
while (N != 0):
    rem = N % 2
    c = pow(10, cnt) 
    B_Number += rem * c 
    N //= 2
    
    # Count used to store exponent value 
    cnt += 1

return B_Number
```

Comment: Please include a description of what your code does and why you believe it answers the question being asked. Code-only answers are considered low quality and are subject to downvoting and/or removal.